# BASH error while doing string manipulation

Tags: bash

I am trying to scan text, but only certain aspects of each line.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
echo $line
destdir=/home/sample.txt
#echo $destdir
#want=${line:3:51}

if [ -f "$destdir" ]
 then 
 echo "${line:3:51}" > "$destdir"

done < "$1"
```

I want to read `file.txt`, and only output the lines starting at the 3rd character, ending at the 54th character, and append the file, `sample.txt`. I am currently getting this error:

```
line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
line 11: `done < "$1"'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `fi` keyword to terminate the `if` statement:

```
if [ -f "$destdir" ]
then 
    echo "${line:3:51}" > "$destdir"
fi
```

However, this is better done with a single call to `cut`:

```
cut -c 3-51 "$1" > /home/sample.txt
```

Comment: So skip those 4 lines altogether, and stick with that one line?

Comment: Skip the entire `while` loop in favor of that one line.

Comment: If I get rid of the whole loop, I just have the one line.. which I'm fine with. However, the sample.txt is telling me that it can't do it - permission denied. I've chmod+x, and still nothing

Comment: `/home/sample.txt` has to be writeable, not executable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant +w... And I"m still getting the error.

Comment: `/home` isn't typically writeable by regular users; did you mean `~/sample.txt`, perhaps?

Comment: It was the ~/sample.txt that was the problem. Thanks. It works like a charm.